# bloc state is the same after coming back to a page even though it was explicitly changed

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a widget that utilizes `CourseBloc`

```
class CourseBloc extends Bloc<CourseEvent, CourseState> {
  final GetCoursesQuery getCoursesQuery;
  final GetSettingsQuery getSettingsQuery;
  final PullCoursesFromServerCommand pullCoursesFromServerCommand;
  final UpdateTasksToServerCommand updateTasksToServerCommand;
  final GetNetworkInfoQuery getNetworkInfoQuery;

  CourseBloc({
    @required GetCoursesQuery getCoursesQuery,
    @required GetSettingsQuery getSettingsQuery,
    @required PullCoursesFromServerCommand pullCoursesFromServerCommand,
    @required UpdateTasksToServerCommand updateTasksToServerCommand,
    @required GetNetworkInfoQuery getNetworkInfoQuery,
  })  : assert(getCoursesQuery != null),
        assert(getSettingsQuery != null),
        assert(pullCoursesFromServerCommand != null),
        assert(updateTasksToServerCommand != null),
        assert(getNetworkInfoQuery != null),
        this.getCoursesQuery = getCoursesQuery,
        this.getSettingsQuery = getSettingsQuery,
        this.pullCoursesFromServerCommand = pullCoursesFromServerCommand,
        this.updateTasksToServerCommand = updateTasksToServerCommand,
        this.getNetworkInfoQuery = getNetworkInfoQuery;

  @override
  CourseState get initialState => CourseInitialState();

  @override
  Stream<CourseState> mapEventToState(
    CourseEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is CoursesReturnedFromTasksEvent) {
      yield CourseInitialState();
    } else if (event is CoursesPageLoadedEvent) {
      yield CourseLoadingState();

      final getCoursesEither = await getCoursesQuery(
        GetCoursesParams(
          truckNumber: event.truckNumber,
        ),
      );

      yield* getCoursesEither.fold((failure) async* {
        yield CourseFetchedStateFailureState(error: "coursesDatabaseError");
      }, (result) async* {
        if (result != null) {
          final getSettingsEither = await getSettingsQuery(NoQueryParams());

          yield* getSettingsEither.fold((failure) async* {
            yield CourseFetchedStateFailureState(error: "coursesDatabaseError");
          }, (settingsResult) async* {
            if (result != null) {
              final networkInfoEither =
                  await this.getNetworkInfoQuery(NoQueryParams());

              yield* networkInfoEither.fold((failure) async* {
                yield CourseErrorState();
              }, (success) async* {
                yield CourseFetchedState(
                  settings: settingsResult,
                  courses: result,
                  isThereInternet: success,
                );
              });
            } else {
              yield CourseFetchedStateFailureState(
                  error: "coursesFetchFromDatabaseError");
            }
          });
        } else {
          yield CourseFetchedStateFailureState(
              error: "coursesFetchFromDatabaseError");
        }
      });
    } else if (event is CoursesRefreshButtonPressedEvent) {
      yield CourseLoadingState();

      final networkInfoEither = await this.getNetworkInfoQuery(NoQueryParams());

      yield* networkInfoEither.fold((failure) async* {
        yield CourseErrorState();
      }, (success) async* {
        if (success) {
          final updateTasksToServerEither = await updateTasksToServerCommand(
              UpdateTasksParams(truckNumber: event.truckNumber));

          yield* updateTasksToServerEither.fold((failure) async* {
            yield CourseFetchedStateFailureState(error: "coursesDatabaseError");
          }, (result) async* {
            final pullCoursesFromServerEither =
                await pullCoursesFromServerCommand(
                    PullCoursesParams(truckNumber: event.truckNumber));

            yield* pullCoursesFromServerEither.fold((failure) async* {
              yield CourseFetchedStateFailureState(
                  error: "coursesDatabaseError");
            }, (result) async* {
              if (result != null) {
                yield CoursePulledFromServerState();
              } else {
                yield CourseFetchedStateFailureState(
                    error: "coursesFetchFromDatabaseError");
              }
            });
          });
        } else {
          yield CourseNoInternetState();
        }
      });
    } else if (event is CoursesRefreshFromTasksButtonPressedEvent) {
      serviceLocator<TaskBloc>().add(
        TasksLoadingEvent(),
      );

      final networkInfoEither = await this.getNetworkInfoQuery(NoQueryParams());

      yield* networkInfoEither.fold((failure) async* {
        serviceLocator<TaskBloc>().add(
          TasksReloadingErrorEvent(),
        );
      }, (success) async* {
        if (success) {
          final updateTasksToServerEither = await updateTasksToServerCommand(
              UpdateTasksParams(truckNumber: event.truckNumber));

          yield* updateTasksToServerEither.fold((failure) async* {
            yield CourseFetchedStateFailureState(error: "coursesDatabaseError");
          }, (result) async* {
            final pullCoursesFromServerEither =
                await pullCoursesFromServerCommand(
                    PullCoursesParams(truckNumber: event.truckNumber));

            yield* pullCoursesFromServerEither.fold((failure) async* {
              serviceLocator<TaskBloc>().add(
                TasksFetchedFailureEvent(failure: "coursesDatabaseError"),
              );
            }, (result) async* {
              if (result != null) {
                serviceLocator<TaskBloc>().add(
                  TasksPulledFromServerEvent(
                    truckNumber: event.truckNumber,
                    courseNumber: event.courseNumber,
                    courseId: event.courseId,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                serviceLocator<TaskBloc>().add(
                  TasksFetchedFailureEvent(
                      failure: "coursesFetchFromDatabaseError"),
                );
              }
            });
          });
        } else {
          yield CourseNoInternetState();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I use `BlocBuilder` and `BlocListener` in the widget page as follows:

```
BlocBuilder<CourseBloc, CourseState>(
   builder: (context, state) {
     if (state is CourseFetchedState) {
     // here I have logic if the course is fetched
   }
...
),

BlocListener<CourseBloc, CourseState>(
   listener: (context, state) {
     if (state is CourseNoInternetState) {
     ...
   }
...
),
```

At some point I am navigating away of this widget. Then I want to come back to this first (Course) widget. I do:

```
serviceLocator<CourseBloc>().add(
     CoursesReturnedFromTasksEvent(),
);

serviceLocator.resetLazySingleton<TaskBloc>(
     instance: serviceLocator<TaskBloc>(),
);

Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

This tells the `CourseBloc` to expect a `CoursesReturnedFromTasksEvent()` , resets the new TaskBloc (because I am not on this page anymore and I don't need to know what state is it at) and pops the current context.

Then I am navigated back. The CourseBloc's mapping method works with the new state and according to the 'if' it yields:

```
if (event is CoursesReturnedFromTasksEvent) {
  yield CourseInitialState();
}
```

But the Builder in the Course page is at the previous state. CourseFetchedState. And it has not 'taken' the new state (Initial).

Any ideas why that might happen?

Here are the States:

```
abstract class CourseState {
  CourseState();
}

class CourseInitialState extends CourseState {}

class CourseReturnedFromTasksState extends CourseState {}

class CourseLoadingState extends CourseState {}

class CourseErrorState extends CourseState {}

class CourseNoInternetState extends CourseState {}

class CoursePulledFromServerState extends CourseState {}

class CourseFetchedState extends CourseState {
  final SettingsAggregate settings;
  final List<CourseAggregate> courses;
  final bool isThereInternet;

  CourseFetchedState({
    @required this.settings,
    @required this.courses,
    @required this.isThereInternet,
  });
}

class CourseFetchedStateFailureState extends CourseState {
  final String error;

  CourseFetchedStateFailureState({@required this.error});
}
```

And Events:

```
abstract class CourseEvent {
  CourseEvent();
}

class CoursesRefreshButtonPressedEvent extends CourseEvent {
  final String truckNumber;

  CoursesRefreshButtonPressedEvent({@required this.truckNumber});
}

class CoursesRefreshFromTasksButtonPressedEvent extends CourseEvent {
  final String courseNumber;
  final String truckNumber;
  final int courseId;

  CoursesRefreshFromTasksButtonPressedEvent({
    @required this.courseNumber,
    @required this.truckNumber,
    @required this.courseId,
  });
}

class CoursesReturnedFromTasksEvent extends CourseEvent {}

class CoursesPageLoadedEvent extends CourseEvent {
  final String truckNumber;

  CoursesPageLoadedEvent({
    this.truckNumber,
  });
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is how the Bloc is provided:

```
Column buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => serviceLocator<CourseBloc>(),
          child: BlocBuilder<CourseBloc, CourseState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is CourseFetchedState) {
              ...
              }
            ...
            }
           ),
          ),
         ],
        );
       }
```

The `serviceLocator()` is instantiated only once, at app startup. It registers all instances needed throughout the app life in order to achieve dependency injection. Here is the `CourseBloc` registration:

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

final serviceLocator = GetIt.instance;
...
serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(
    () => CourseBloc(
      getCoursesQuery: serviceLocator(),
      getSettingsQuery: serviceLocator(),
      pullCoursesFromServerCommand: serviceLocator(),
      updateTasksToServerCommand: serviceLocator(),
      getNetworkInfoQuery: serviceLocator(),
    ),
  );
...
```

Comment: How do you provide your Bloc to the widget tree?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have edited the question and added the providing mechanism at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really familiar with `GetIt`, but from what I can tell:

1. You make a singleton of `CourseBloc` with `serviceLocator`.
2. You use `BlocProvider` to provide that singleton to the relevant context (Resulting in 2 instances of `CourseBloc`).
3. Your `BlocBuilder` uses the instance provided via `BlocProvider` because you don't explicitly tell via `bloc` parameter (It will look up the widget tree to find `CourseBloc` within the same context).
4. You use the instance of `CourseBloc` made by `serviceLocator` to add `CoursesReturnedFromTasksEvent()`.

Try adding event the usual way via `BlocProvider.of`, but you still need manually dispose the `CourseBloc` singleton made by `serviceLocator`

```
BlocProvider.of<CourseBloc>(context).add(
  CoursesReturnedFromTasksEvent(),
);
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer!!! I tried first removing the BlocProvider instances I am using (three times in my code for that page - I might be doing it wrong, but I basically provide the bloc before I use the builder or listener). Then I added the bloc: parameter to every occurrence of BlocBuilder (2 instances) and BlocListener (1 instance). I am getting the error: BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type CourseBloc. at the first time I try to create the Listener. Could you please explain a bit more how am I getting two instances of that Bloc?

Comment: In addition - what (where) is the best practice to dispose of a Bloc instance?

Comment: Sorry I think my answer confused you. What I meant was, it looks kind of two instances because the BlocProvider doesn't directly handle CourseBloc. And for disposing, the best place is the same place it's provided initially

Comment: Your comment on the two instances of the same Bloc was very good! I noticed that the mapper function did work on the new events that come after returning back from the other page. But the state of the Bloc in the Courses page was the old one => another instance. I saw that I have used another Provider in the Tasks page where I want to use a functionality of the Course bloc. So I provide it again. That was the error. I now don't provide it, but use the exact same instance from the previous widget. Please, put your answer back, it was very good!